# web service deployment with no class found error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss, wildfly

I created a web service and deployed it to server successfully. But when I tried to send a request I got the error message like below:
[image: log files]
The error happened at below code:

```
Service service1 =null;
try {
    service1=new Service();
```

I already added the related jar files in project as attached screen.
Can anyone tell me why?Thx[image: ![screenshot of eclipse]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLiEE.png)

Comment: Can you paste all of the exception, plus possible Cause by exceptions?

Comment: Why you don't use maven? Things can get messy if you add jars by hand..

Comment: I updated the log file.